# Drupal : how to create a view that displays all the content-types

Tags: drupal, view

It may sound 'weird' but I need to have a view that lists all the content types I have.

For example i have two content types : contenttypeA, contenttypeB

I want to create a view that just displays the two content types (and show number of items of that type, but that can be done later).

For now what I did is add one content of each content type and list them but only show the 'node type'; it works well if there's at least one content but I want to display even without any content of that content type.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a Customfield: PHP code field and custom code the whole thing with PHP. This is provided by the [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) module.
2. Use the [Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw) module to make the node_type table available to views. You may need to use the [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module as well since they say that all future development is going there.
3. Expose the node_type table yourself by writing a custom module using the Views API as suggested by chx.

Number one is the quick and dirty way, but number 2 might be a little more manageable, but I am not completely sure it will do everything you want. If you do number 3 make sure you contribute back to the community by putting your module on drupal.org.

Comment: Wow ok; not sure i 'yet' have the skills to write out a custom module but will give a try to customfield first; if you have time to write the module that "would" be great !

Answer (score 2):

Introducing the node_type table to Views requires a custom module and some Views API knowledge however http://drupal.org/node/1001222 will give you a head start.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native functionality in Views to do that.  You can write a static page or (overkill) a module that provide a "system"-like type similar to [Views Watchdog](http://drupal.org/project/views_watchdog).